# (Local Host ) SQL Server 2014 is not communicating with Weigh scale

Tags: localhost, sql-server-2014, communication, modbus-tcp

I am trying to communicate the weigh scale device Mettler Toledo (IND131) to my localhost but it was not established.

The IP address for my weigh scale is 192.168.0.1 and I changed the same in the SQL Server. hence I ping the IP address of the weigh scale device via command prompt from PC and it was healthy.

Is there is any other location that I want to change the IP address in the SQL server?

And I try the Modbus test using Modscan software to confirm the status of the weigh scale and it was working good.

Please see the server configuration manager in the attached image whether we need to change anything over there because the TCP/IP port was disabled previously, I enabled it and I tested again but no use so I kept it as disabled.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3t19E.png)

Comment: You should be more **careful** with your SQL Server version numbers..... "14" can either mean "2014" (as it seems in your case), but the internal version number "SQL Server v14" refers to SQL Server **2017** ..... so when you write "SQL Server 14" it's **not** immediately clear whether you mean **2014** or v14 = **2017** ......

Comment: SQL SERVER 2014